# Laravel API Resource not returning correct value with condition

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel API, I want to return a book where recommended === 1

In my resources, I have this

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'about' => $this->about,
        'content' => $this->content,
      //  'image' => asset('/storage/'.$this->image),
      'image' => $this->image_url,
       // 'recommended' => $this->recommended,
        'recommended' => $this->when($this->recommended === 1, $this->recommended),
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'author' => $this->author,
   ];
```

I want to return books when recommended === 1

My table is Like this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('about');
        $table->string('image');  
        $table->string('image_url');
        $table->string('epub_url');
        $table->integer('author_id'); 
        $table->string('publisher');  
        $table->year('year');
        $table->boolean('recommended')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();    
    });
```

I was able to achieve the same thing on web using this

```
public function index()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['recommends'] = Book::where('recommended', 1)->take(10)->get();
    $data['latests'] = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
   return view('welcome', compact("data"));
}
```

But I don't know how to replicate the same using Laravel API.

#### UPDATE

I was able to achieve the same thing on web using this

```
public function index()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['recommends'] = Book::where('recommended', 1)->take(10)->get();
    $data['latests'] = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
   return view('welcome', compact("data"));
}
```

But I don't know how to replicate the same using Laravel API.

Normally I will get all Books or Post like this using API Resource

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'about' => $this->about,
        'content' => $this->content,
        'image' => $this->image_url,
        'recommended' => $this->recommended,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'author' => $this->author,
   ];
```

and call it like this in my controller

```
public function indexapi()
{
  return BookResource::collection(Book::with('author')->Paginate(16));
}
```

But there some cases `recommended` is == 1 and some `recommended` == 0, in this case, I want to return data only when recommended == 1

I know my question is quite confusing

Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: return what book? what is this resource for in the first place

Comment: Example: I want to return a post where the post is recommended. By default, I set recommended to 0, this make it not to be recommended, but when it is recommended it must == 1. That's what I am trying to achieve here. Thanks.

Comment: the `when` method is for conditionally adding an attribute, not whether you are returning an entire resource, feel that should be done before you are returning the resource at all ... add to your question how you are using this API resource

Comment: Can you please explain in the form of code, I will understand better like that and  it would enable to solve similar problem on my own. Thanks.

Comment: you provide code ... it is confusing what you think you are trying to do here

Comment: Please can you check my updated question?

Comment: why dont you filter them before you pass them to the resource? only pass the records you actually want to use

Comment: Okay, I haven't heard of that before. I will research on that. Thanks.

Comment: if you only want records where `recommended` equals 1, then only query the database for those records

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have been able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right,  you want to filter & get only the books with ( recommended attribute == 1 ). If thats the case you shouldn't do it in your Collection file. You should do this filtering process in your Controller before passing any data to Collection.

Here is some code example from one of my project.

**In ProductController.php FILE**

```
public function index()
{
    return new ProductCollection( Product::where('recommended','1')->get() );
}
```

As you can see , I'm filtering the products to get only the recommended ones. Then I'm sending this filtered data to the ProductCollection. This way The collection will only return the data I want.

**In ProductCollection.php FILE**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection->map( function($data) {
            return [
                'id' => (integer) $data->id,
                'name' => $data->name,
                'category_id' => $data->category_id,
                'brand_id' => $data->brand_id,
                'photos' => json_decode($data->photos),
                'gtin' => $data->gtin
            ];
        })
    ];
}
```

I don't have to make any changes in Collection. Because in this way , Collection should do the job for every data it gets.